# Adding XHR to Vue JS webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I'm trying to add [XHR](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr) to Vue.  I get the error XHR is not defined.  I followed the XHR instructions, installed with NPM, added it to the webpack.base file under alias. I'm calling it inside a template file the Hello.vue file that comes with the vue-cli boiler plate.  I use "npm run dev" do I need to rebuild somehow?

```
resolve: {
extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
alias: {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
  '@': resolve('src'),
  'request$': 'xhr'
}
```

},

From Hello.vue inside the  tag

```
xhr({
uri: "http://localhost:8081/service",
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

}, function (err, resp, body) {
    list = resp;
})
```

Code in Hello.vue

```
    <script>
var xhr = require("xhr")

var spells = [];

function doGetSpells(){

        //var self = this;
        xhr({
          uri: "http://localhost:8081/spellNames",
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
      }, function (err, resp, body) {              
          spells = JSON.parse(body);
          console.log(spells);
      })           
}

export default {
  name: 'sideBar',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      spellList: spells   
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getSpells(){
      doGetSpells();
    },
    mounted () {
      doGetSpells();
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: can you show the code that you have used in Hello.vue?

Comment: I added it to the original post.

Comment: Did you added `var xhr = require("xhr")` in the Hello.vue. Can you show the full hello.vue?

Comment: No the only place I saw that had similar requirements was in the web pack base file.  I wasn't aware you could put the require in the Vue files

Comment: I got it to return data, now to figure out how to get the callback to set the variable.

Comment: I updated the OP, having issues getting the object to update on callback.  I thought using the mounted event would do it.

Comment: Figured that part out too, just had to pass the "this" object through to the xhr function.  Jewel if you post an answer about the require("xhr") I'll select that one.  That was the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
var xhr = require("xhr")

xhr.get('/post-to-me', function(err, resp) {
   // callback
})
```

You should pass a callback function as parameters, it will be called when the action is done.

In your callback, you will have access to your Vue instance using "this":

```
this.spellList = []
```